# How to trigger EPOLLIN and EPOLLOUT events?

Tags: c++, file-descriptor, epoll

I'm writing Epoll based program where I want to read a hash-map object as soon as data is added to it,using threads and epoll events.

Can someone maybe provide an explanation here, or point me to a good high level tutorial on how epoll works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>`enter code here`
#include <iterator> 
#include <map> 
#define MAX_EVENTS 5
#define READ_SIZE 10
#include <stdio.h>     // for fprintf()
#include <unistd.h>    // for close(), read()
#include <sys/epoll.h> // for epoll_create1(), epoll_ctl(), struct epoll_event
#include <string.h>  

std::map<int, std::string> mp; 
std::map<int, std::string>::iterator it = mp.begin();


void set()
{
    mp.insert(std::make_pair(1,"earth"));
    mp.insert(std::make_pair(2,"moon")); 
     std::cout<<"Inserted"<<std::endl;   
}


void get()
{    
        for (auto itr = mp.begin(); itr != mp.end(); ++itr) { 
        std::cout << itr->first << '\t' << itr->second << '\n'; 
    } 

}

int main()  
{

    struct epoll_event event;
    int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);

    event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT; 

    std::thread threadObj1(set);

    std::thread threadObj2(get);
    threadObj1.join(); 
    threadObj2.join(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have the peers sed some data to the connection or read some data from it, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with epoll you'll ask it to start listening for events on file descriptors that represent sockets, much as you would with `select`.

In this case, instead of sockets, you want an FD that is "mocked" so you can "trigger" it at will to represent some changed condition without actually sending any data.

This is what [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) is for.

Comment: I'm not going to reproduce it here, because SO's licensing is utterly f#cked, but there's [some example code on github](https://gist.github.com/nineright/9431572). Otherwise it's not hard to put together from the info on the manpage.